How to create a manifest file for a webapp in IOS where the root is a subfolder (application) on an IIS server
I would like users to save my site as a shortcut in IOS. The source of my app is located on an IIS Server but not in the root folder. It is a subfolder eg. myapplication (a stand-alone application) and theoretically has nothing to do with the root folder.
Following the standard guidelines for manifest files only works if the webapp is in the root, how do I change the manifest to allow subfolder saves?
https://www.example.com/myapplication
Here is my manifest file. I have tried all combinations but IOS does not want to recognise anything unless it's in the root folder (which I theoretically do not have access to)
{
  "name": "My Standalone App",
  "short_name": "MyApp",
  "start_url": "index",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/icons-192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons-512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "scope": ".",
  "apple": {
    "status_bar_style": "black-translucent"
  }
}

